# Помогите пожалуйста с UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Задача такова:
Обновить значение `salary` в таблице `employees` установив заработные платы для
сотрудников по следующим правилам:
Если итоговая выручка за последний год составляет от 10000 и более - удвоить текущее значение.

Я пишу:

```
UPDATE employees
SET salary = salary * 2 
WHERE EXISTS   (
  SELECT e.first_name, sum (amount) as total_amt, YEAR (CAST (sales_time AS DATE)) AS SALES_DATE
  FROM sales s join employees e on s.employee_id = e.id
  GROUP BY e.first_name, YEAR(CAST(sales_time AS DATE))
  having  YEAR(CAST(sales_time AS DATE)) = 2017
  AND sum (amount) > 10000
)
```

и у меня обновляются зарплаты не тех двух человек, которые выбираются в этом select, а всех что есть. Где моя ошибка?

Comment: работаю с MSSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то вы очень сложно все написали.

Ваша ошибка в том, что подзапрос у вас никак не коррелирует с внешним запросом, поэтому для каждой записи из `employees` он будет возвращать записи и условие `EXISTS` будет срабатывать всегда

```
UPDATE employees e SET
  e.salary = e.salary * 2 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    sales s
  WHERE
    s.employee_id = e.id AND
    YEAR(CAST(sales_time AS DATE)) = 2017
  HAVING
    sum(s.amount) >= 10000
)
```

В подзапросе выбираем записи, относящиеся к текущему человеку по продажам за 2017 год и с суммой продаж больше или равной 10000